# bootstrap no-gutter grid system not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found some code on internet on how to make bootstrap grid gutter lass.
I am using bs v3.3.1
my code snippet is

```
.row.no-gutter{
     margin-left:0px !important;
     margin-right:0px !important;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
     padding-right:0;
     padding-left:0;
 }
```

and my implementation is :

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

i am using css only .. NO LESS or SASS

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I don't see any questions here... Would you like to share what you're trying to accomplish, with us?

Answer (score -1):

I think the most appropriate way is to go to bootstrap customize http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system and set @grid-gutter-width=0 so you won't have gutter padding.